# Simple raw_input code not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, raw-input

I honestly have no clue why this code isn't working. When the code runs, no matter what I input, it always returns "Goodbye. Have a nice day!" Can anyone see why?

```
again = raw_input("Would you like to restart? ").lower()
if again == "no" or "n":
    print "Goodbye. Have a nice day!"
    loop = 0
elif again == "yes" or "y":
    loop = 1
else:
    print "Answer invalid. Have a nice day!"
    loop = 0
```

(There is a section of code before this which is in a loop when 'loop' variable is 0. That's why there are loop variable edits following the 'if', 'elif', and 'else' statements.